The bottom margin of bibliography frame is too narrow
I have a beamer document:
\begin{filecontents}{bib.bib}
@article{bolte2024swarm,
  title={Swarm gradient dynamics for global optimization: the mean-field limit case},
  author={Bolte, J{\'e}r{\^o}me and Miclo, Laurent and Villeneuve, St{\'e}phane},
  journal={Mathematical Programming},
  volume={205},
  number={1},
  pages={661--701},
  year={2024},
  publisher={Springer}
}
@article{wang2023singular,
  title={Singular density dependent stochastic differential equations},
  author={Wang, Feng-Yu},
  journal={Journal of Differential Equations},
  volume={361},
  pages={562--589},
  year={2023},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}
@article{hao_strong_2024,
    title = {Strong {Convergence} of {Propagation} of {Chaos} for {McKean}–{Vlasov} {SDEs} with {Singular} {Interactions}},
    volume = {56},
    issn = {0036-1410, 1095-7154},
    doi = {10.1137/23M1556666},
    language = {en},
    number = {2},
    urldate = {2024-03-31},
    journal = {SIAM Journal on Mathematical Analysis},
    author = {Hao, Zimo and Röckner, Michael and Zhang, Xicheng},
    month = apr,
    year = {2024},
    pages = {2661--2713}
}
@misc{zhang_second_2022,
    title = {Second order {McKean}-{Vlasov} {SDEs} and kinetic {Fokker}-{Planck}-{Kolmogorov} equations},
    url = {http://arxiv.org/abs/2109.01273},
    urldate = {2024-07-27},
    publisher = {arXiv},
    author = {Zhang, Xicheng},
    month = jan,
    year = {2022},
    note = {arXiv:2109.01273 [math]}
}
@article{huang2022singular,
  title={Singular {McKean}-{Vlasov} (reflecting) SDEs with distribution dependent noise},
  author={Huang, Xing and Wang, Feng-Yu},
  journal={Journal of Mathematical Analysis and Applications},
  volume={514},
  number={1},
  pages={126301},
  year={2022},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}
@article{bencheikh_convergence_2022,
    title = {Convergence in {Total} {Variation} of the {Euler}-{Maruyama} {Scheme} {Applied} to {Diffusion} {Processes} with {Measurable} {Drift} {Coefficient} and {Additive} {Noise}},
    volume = {60},
    issn = {0036-1429, 1095-7170},
    url = {https://epubs.siam.org/doi/10.1137/20M1371774},
    doi = {10.1137/20M1371774},
    language = {en},
    number = {4},
    urldate = {2024-01-05},
    journal = {SIAM Journal on Numerical Analysis},
    author = {Bencheikh, Oumaima and Jourdain, Benjamin},
    month = aug,
    year = {2022},
    pages = {1701--1740},
}
@article{jourdain_convergence_2024,
author = {Benjamin Jourdain and St{\'e}phane Menozzi},
title = {{Convergence rate of the Euler–Maruyama scheme applied to diffusion processes with  drift coefficient and additive noise}},
volume = {34},
journal = {The Annals of Applied Probability},
number = {1B},
publisher = {Institute of Mathematical Statistics},
pages = {1663 -- 1697},
keywords = {Diffusion processes, Euler scheme, Singular drift, weak error analysis},
year = {2024},
doi = {10.1214/23-AAP2006},
URL = {https://doi.org/10.1214/23-AAP2006}
}
@misc{le_taming_2022,
    title = {Taming singular stochastic differential equations: {A} numerical method},
    shorttitle = {Taming singular stochastic differential equations},
    url = {http://arxiv.org/abs/2110.01343},
    urldate = {2024-04-05},
    publisher = {arXiv},
    author = {Lê, Khoa and Ling, Chengcheng},
    month = jun,
    year = {2022},
    note = {arXiv:2110.01343 [cs, math]},
}
@article{de_angelis_numerical_2022,
    title = {A numerical scheme for stochastic differential equations with distributional drift},
    volume = {154},
    issn = {03044149},
    url = {https://linkinghub.elsevier.com/retrieve/pii/S0304414922001946},
    doi = {10.1016/j.spa.2022.09.003},
    language = {en},
    urldate = {2024-07-28},
    journal = {Stochastic Processes and their Applications},
    author = {De Angelis, Tiziano and Germain, Maximilien and Issoglio, Elena},
    month = dec,
    year = {2022},
    pages = {55--90},
}
@misc{jaquez_convergence_2023,
    title = {Convergence rate of numerical scheme for {SDEs} with a distributional drift in {Besov} space},
    url = {http://arxiv.org/abs/2309.11396},
    urldate = {2024-07-28},
    publisher = {arXiv},
    author = {Jáquez, Luis Mario Chaparro and Issoglio, Elena and Palczewski, Jan},
    month = sep,
    year = {2023},
    note = {arXiv:2309.11396 [cs, math]},
}
@article{hao2021euler,
  title={Euler scheme for density dependent stochastic differential equations},
  author={Hao, Zimo and R{\"o}ckner, Michael and Zhang, Xicheng},
  journal={Journal of Differential Equations},
  volume={274},
  pages={996--1014},
  year={2021},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}
@phdthesis{hao_phd_2023,
    title = {{McKean}-{Vlasov} {SDEs} with singular drifts},
        school   = {Universität Bielefeld},
    copyright = {Creative Commons Zero v1.0 Universal},
    url = {https://pub.uni-bielefeld.de/record/2980828},
    doi = {10.4119/UNIBI/2980828},
    urldate = {2024-01-14},
    author = {Hao, Zimo},
    year = {2023},
    keywords = {510},
    pages = {1051153 bytes},
}
@article{wu_well-posedness_2023,
    title = {Well-posedness of density dependent {SDE} driven by {$\alpha$}-stable process with {Hölder} drifts},
    volume = {164},
    issn = {03044149},
    url = {https://linkinghub.elsevier.com/retrieve/pii/S0304414923001515},
    doi = {10.1016/j.spa.2023.07.016},
    language = {en},
    urldate = {2024-01-05},
    journal = {Stochastic Processes and their Applications},
    author = {Wu, Mingyan and Hao, Zimo},
    month = oct,
    year = {2023},
    pages = {416--442},
}
@misc{song_convergence_2024,
    title = {Convergence rate of the {Euler}-{Maruyama} scheme to density dependent {SDEs} driven by {$\alpha$}-stable additive noise},
    url = {http://arxiv.org/abs/2405.20840},
    urldate = {2024-06-07},
    publisher = {arXiv},
    author = {Song, Ke and Hao, Zimo},
    month = may,
    year = {2024},
    note = {arXiv:2405.20840 [math]},
}
@misc{le2024wellposedness,
      title={Well-posedness of {McKean}-{Vlasov} SDEs with density-dependent drift}, 
      author={Anh-Dung Le},
      year={2024},
      eprint={2404.19499},
      archivePrefix={arXiv},
      primaryClass={math.PR},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{parskip}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle continuation}{\gdef\beamer@frametitle{}}
\addtobeamertemplate{block begin}{\vfill}{}
\addtobeamertemplate{block begin}{}{\setlength{\parskip}{0.4\baselineskip}}
\setbeamersize{text margin left=0.35cm,text margin right=0.35cm}
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks=true,
  linkcolor=blue,
  filecolor=blue,
  urlcolor=red,
  citecolor=magenta
}
\usepackage[
  doi=false,
  isbn=false,
  url=false,
  eprint=false,
  sorting=none,
  style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bib.bib}
\renewcommand\bibfont{\scriptsize}
\setlength{\bibitemsep}{1ex plus 2pt minus 2pt}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\begin{document}

\setlength{\parskip}{\fill}

\begin{frame}{}

We have \cite{bolte2024swarm,wang2023singular,hao_strong_2024,zhang_second_2022,huang2022singular,bencheikh_convergence_2022,jourdain_convergence_2024,le_taming_2022,de_angelis_numerical_2022,jaquez_convergence_2023,hao2021euler,hao_phd_2023,wu_well-posedness_2023,song_convergence_2024,le2024wellposedness}.

\end{frame}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
\setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}{}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks,noframenumbering]{References}

\printbibliography[heading=none]

\end{frame}

\end{document}

The bottom margin of the first page of bibliography is fine for me:

However, The bottom margin of the second page of bibliography is too narrow:

Could you elaborate on this phenomenon and how to remedy it?

Would work as it should if you'd use the default beamer parskip.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I would like to use \setlength{\parskip}{\fill} to take use of the "redundant" space...

@Akira - In your learned opinion, how many participants in all beamer presentations you may give over your entire professional career will notice, let alone care one bit about, how you handle "redundant space"? (Hint: The number may be very close to zero...) Just specify t (for "top-alignment") as one of the beamer document class options and make life easy and comfortable for yourself and the consumers of your beamer presentations.

Rather than "make use of redundant space", as you put it, I'd focus on keeping the layout simple and clean, for instance by loading the beamer class with the option t (short for "top-aligned"). And I'd definitely make an effort to remove formatting inconsistencies from various title fields. (E.g., instead of {Fokker}-{Planck}-{Kolmogorov}, why not {Fokker--Planck--Kolmogorov}?) I'd also run \renewbibmacro{in:}{} to get rid of the pointless "In:" prefixes for entries of type @article. Some fields obviously contain incorrect information; see, e.g., pages = {1051153 bytes}. Finally, I've noticed that some bib entries practice sentence style, while others practice title style. I think you should settle on one style or the other.
Aside: I also think that it's not a good idea to impose \scriptsize on the contents of the bibliography, unless you want to guarantee that nobody is going to bother perusing the bibliography.
The following screenshot shows the first of three bibliography-related frames that result from making the adjustments suggested above.

\documentclass[t]{beamer} % 't' option for top-alignment of frame contents

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{bib.bib}
@article{bolte2024swarm,
  title={Swarm gradient dynamics for global optimization: the mean-field limit case},
  author={Bolte, Jérôme and Miclo, Laurent and Villeneuve, Stéphane},
  journal={Mathematical Programming},
  volume={205},
  number={1},
  pages={661--701},
  year={2024},
  publisher={Springer}
}
@article{wang2023singular,
  title={Singular density dependent stochastic differential equations},
  author={Wang, Feng-Yu},
  journal={Journal of Differential Equations},
  volume={361},
  pages={562--589},
  year={2023},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}
@article{hao_strong_2024,
    title = {Strong Convergence of Propagation of Chaos for {McKean--Vlasov SDEs} with Singular Interactions},
    volume = {56},
    issn = {0036-1410, 1095-7154},
    doi = {10.1137/23M1556666},
    language = {en},
    number = {2},
    urldate = {2024-03-31},
    journal = {SIAM Journal on Mathematical Analysis},
    author = {Hao, Zimo and Röckner, Michael and Zhang, Xicheng},
    month = apr,
    year = {2024},
    pages = {2661--2713}
}
@misc{zhang_second_2022,
    title = {Second order {McKean--Vlasov SDEs} and kinetic {Fokker--Planck--Kolmogorov} equations},
    url = {http://arxiv.org/abs/2109.01273},
    urldate = {2024-07-27},
    publisher = {arXiv},
    author = {Zhang, Xicheng},
    month = jan,
    year = {2022},
    note = {arXiv:2109.01273 [math]}
}
@article{huang2022singular,
  title={Singular {McKean--Vlasov} (reflecting) {SDEs} with distribution dependent noise},
  author={Huang, Xing and Wang, Feng-Yu},
  journal={Journal of Mathematical Analysis and Applications},
  volume={514},
  number={1},
  pages={126301},
  year={2022},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}
@article{bencheikh_convergence_2022,
    title = {Convergence in Total Variation of the {Euler--Maruyama} Scheme Applied to Diffusion Processes with Measurable Drift Coefficient and Additive Noise},
    volume = {60},
    issn = {0036-1429, 1095-7170},
    url = {https://epubs.siam.org/doi/10.1137/20M1371774},
    doi = {10.1137/20M1371774},
    language = {en},
    number = {4},
    urldate = {2024-01-05},
    journal = {SIAM Journal on Numerical Analysis},
    author = {Bencheikh, Oumaima and Jourdain, Benjamin},
    month = aug,
    year = {2022},
    pages = {1701--1740},
}
@article{jourdain_convergence_2024,
author = {Benjamin Jourdain and Stéphane Menozzi},
title = {Convergence rate of the {Euler--Maruyama} scheme applied to diffusion processes with drift coefficient and additive noise},
volume = {34},
journal = {The Annals of Applied Probability},
number = {1B},
publisher = {Institute of Mathematical Statistics},
pages = {1663 -- 1697},
keywords = {Diffusion processes, Euler scheme, Singular drift, weak error analysis},
year = {2024},
doi = {10.1214/23-AAP2006},
URL = {https://doi.org/10.1214/23-AAP2006}
}
@misc{le_taming_2022,
    title = {Taming singular stochastic differential equations: {A} numerical method},
    shorttitle = {Taming singular stochastic differential equations},
    url = {http://arxiv.org/abs/2110.01343},
    urldate = {2024-04-05},
    publisher = {arXiv},
    author = {Lê, Khoa and Ling, Chengcheng},
    month = jun,
    year = {2022},
    note = {arXiv:2110.01343 [cs, math]},
}
@article{de_angelis_numerical_2022,
    title = {A numerical scheme for stochastic differential equations with distributional drift},
    volume = {154},
    issn = {03044149},
    url = {https://linkinghub.elsevier.com/retrieve/pii/S0304414922001946},
    doi = {10.1016/j.spa.2022.09.003},
    language = {en},
    urldate = {2024-07-28},
    journal = {Stochastic Processes and their Applications},
    author = {De Angelis, Tiziano and Germain, Maximilien and Issoglio, Elena},
    month = dec,
    year = {2022},
    pages = {55--90},
}
@misc{jaquez_convergence_2023,
    title = {Convergence rate of numerical scheme for {SDEs} with a distributional drift in {Besov} space},
    url = {http://arxiv.org/abs/2309.11396},
    urldate = {2024-07-28},
    publisher = {arXiv},
    author = {Jáquez, Luis Mario Chaparro and Issoglio, Elena and Palczewski, Jan},
    month = sep,
    year = {2023},
    note = {arXiv:2309.11396 [cs, math]},
}
@article{hao2021euler,
  title={Euler scheme for density dependent stochastic differential equations},
  author={Hao, Zimo and Röckner, Michael and Zhang, Xicheng},
  journal={Journal of Differential Equations},
  volume={274},
  pages={996--1014},
  year={2021},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}
@phdthesis{hao_phd_2023,
    title    = {{McKean--Vlasov SDEs} with singular drifts},
    school   = {Universität Bielefeld},
    copyright= {Creative Commons Zero v1.0 Universal},
    url      = {https://pub.uni-bielefeld.de/record/2980828},
    doi      = {10.4119/UNIBI/2980828},
    urldate  = {2024-01-14},
    author   = {Hao, Zimo},
    year     = {2023},
    keywords = {510},
    pages = {1051153 bytes},
}
@article{wu_well-posedness_2023,
    title = {Well-posedness of density dependent {SDE} driven by $\alpha$-stable process with {Hölder} drifts},
    volume = {164},
    issn = {03044149},
    url = {https://linkinghub.elsevier.com/retrieve/pii/S0304414923001515},
    doi = {10.1016/j.spa.2023.07.016},
    language = {en},
    urldate = {2024-01-05},
    journal = {Stochastic Processes and their Applications},
    author = {Wu, Mingyan and Hao, Zimo},
    month = oct,
    year = {2023},
    pages = {416--442},
}
@misc{song_convergence_2024,
    title = {Convergence rate of the {Euler--Maruyama} scheme to density dependent {SDEs} driven by $\alpha$-stable additive noise},
    url = {http://arxiv.org/abs/2405.20840},
    urldate = {2024-06-07},
    publisher = {arXiv},
    author = {Song, Ke and Hao, Zimo},
    month = may,
    year = {2024},
    note = {arXiv:2405.20840 [math]},
}
@misc{le2024wellposedness,
      title={Well-posedness of {McKean--Vlasov SDEs} with density-dependent drift}, 
      author={Anh-Dung Le},
      year={2024},
      eprint={2404.19499},
      archivePrefix={arXiv},
      primaryClass={math.PR},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{xurl} % <-- new
\usepackage{parskip} % are you sure about this?
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle continuation}{\gdef\beamer@frametitle{}}
\addtobeamertemplate{block begin}{\vfill}{}
\addtobeamertemplate{block begin}{}{\setlength{\parskip}{0.4\baselineskip}}
\setbeamersize{text margin left=0.35cm,text margin right=0.35cm}
\hypersetup{
     colorlinks=true,
     linkcolor=blue,
     filecolor=blue,
     urlcolor=red,
     citecolor=magenta
}
\usepackage[
     doi=false,
     isbn=false,
     url=false,
     eprint=false,
     sorting=none,
     style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
     
\addbibresource{bib.bib}
\renewcommand\bibfont{\small} % please not '\scriptsize'
\renewbibmacro{in:}{}
\setlength{\bibitemsep}{1ex plus 2pt minus 2pt}

\usepackage{sansmathfonts} % <-- new

\begin{document}

%\setlength{\parskip}{\fill} % please don't

\begin{frame}

We have \cite{bolte2024swarm, wang2023singular, hao_strong_2024, zhang_second_2022, huang2022singular, bencheikh_convergence_2022, jourdain_convergence_2024, le_taming_2022, de_angelis_numerical_2022, jaquez_convergence_2023, hao2021euler, hao_phd_2023, wu_well-posedness_2023, song_convergence_2024, le2024wellposedness}.

\end{frame}


\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
\setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}{}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks,noframenumbering]{References}

\printbibliography[heading=none]

\end{frame}

\end{document}

